# From AsyncTask to RxJava2: How to emit progress messages and result object?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, rx-java2

I'm using an `AsyncTask` to download files from a server and after downloading them they are processed in an iteration.

The download issues `String` progress messages like "Connecting...", "Downloaded..." and the processing issues `String` progress messages like "Processed file 1/5",  "Processed file 2/5".

When all is done, a final `List<File>` object is returned.

In the AsyncTask I have a clear separation between progress and result, each method can pass different parameter types, where progress would be of type `String` and result of type `List<File>`

How can I model this with RxJava2?

What I've done now is created a class `Emission`

```
private static class Emission {
    public enum Type {PROGRESS, RESULT}
    public Type m_eType;
    public Integer m_iIndex;
    public String m_strMessage;
    public List<Files> m_lfFiles;
    public Emission(List<Files>lfFiles) {
        m_eType = Type.RESULT;
        m_lfFiles = lfFiles;
    }
    public Emission(Integer iIndex, String strMessage) {
        m_eType = Type.PROGRESS;
        m_iIndex = iIndex;
        m_strMessage = strMessage;
    }
}
```

and I emit the progress like this:

```
e.onNext(new Emission(0, "Connecting..."));
...
e.onNext(new Emission(3, "Processing file 3/4"));
e.onNext(new Emission(4, "Processing file 4/4"));
```

and the final result like this

```
e.onNext(new Emission(lfFiles));
```

The observer is basically doing the following

```
@Override public void onNext(Emission e) {
    if (e.m_eType == Emission.Type.PROGRESS) {
        if (dlgDownload != null) {
            dlgDownload.setProgress(e.m_iIndex);
            dlgDownload.setContent(e.m_strMessage);
        }
    }
    if (e.m_eType == Emission.Type.RESULT) {
        ...
```

This feels a bit weird. Is there a better way to do this, like subscribe two Observers where each one takes a different type and only reacts to emissions of their type?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can split the reactive stream in two by using `filter` operator and then work with each stream individually.

First of all you take the source observable and apply the `share` operator to it, so you can have multiple subscribers to the same observable:

```
Observable<Emission> sharedObservable = Observable.just(
        new Emission(0, "Connecting..."),
        new Emission(1, "Processing file 1/2"),
        new Emission(2, "Processing file 2/2"),
        new Emission(new ArrayList<String>() {{ this.add("1.txt"); this.add("2.txt"); }})
).share();
```

Then, by using `filter` operator you create two streams from one:

```
Disposable disposable1 = sharedObservable.filter(new Predicate<Emission>() {
    public boolean test(Emission emission) throws Exception {
        return emission.m_eType == Emission.Type.PROGRESS;
    }
}).subscribe(new Consumer<Emission>() {
    public void accept(Emission emission) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("progress = " + emission.m_iIndex);
    }
});

Disposable disposable2 = sharedObservable.filter(new Predicate<Emission>() {
    public boolean test(Emission emission) throws Exception {
        return emission.m_eType == Emission.Type.RESULT;
    }
}).subscribe(new Consumer<Emission>() {
    public void accept(Emission emission) throws Exception {
        for (String file : emission.m_lfFiles) {
            System.out.println("file = " + file);
        }
    }
});
```

Result:

```
progress = 0
progress = 1
progress = 2
file = 1.txt
file = 2.txt
```

**UPDATE**.

Here is another way to achieve the same result by using polymorphism.
You have to introduce a base class `Emission` and have two children `ProgressEmission` and `FileEmission` extend it (you can also remove `m_eType` since we wont need it):

```
abstract class Emission {
}

class ProgressEmission extends Emission {
    public String m_strMessage;
    public Integer m_iIndex;

    public ProgressEmission(Integer iIndex, String strMessage) {
        m_iIndex = iIndex;
        m_strMessage = strMessage;
    }
}

class FileEmission extends Emission {
    public List<String> m_lfFiles;

    public FileEmission(List<String> lfFiles) {
        m_lfFiles = lfFiles;
    }
}
```

Now, to differentiate emissions we can use java's `instanceof` operator:

```
Disposable disposable = Observable.just(
        new ProgressEmission(0, "Connecting..."),
        new ProgressEmission(1, "Processing file 1/2"),
        new ProgressEmission(2, "Processing file 2/2"),
        new FileEmission(new ArrayList<String>() {{
            this.add("1.txt");
            this.add("2.txt");
        }})
).subscribe(new Consumer<Emission>() {
    public void accept(Emission emission) throws Exception {
        if (emission instanceof ProgressEmission) {
            ProgressEmission progressEmission = (ProgressEmission) emission;
            System.out.println("progress = " + progressEmission.m_iIndex);
        } else {
            FileEmission fileEmission = (FileEmission) emission;

            for (String file : fileEmission.m_lfFiles) {
                System.out.println("file = " + file);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I actually want to get rid of the `Emission` class and emit two different types in one Observable, which is then observed by two Observers, one for each type. Or have like two `onNext` in one Observer, one for each type.

Comment: Then you can make a base class Emission and two children classes something like ProgressEmission and FileEmission that extend Emission. Then you can split the stream by comparing the instances of the classes (like: emission instanceof FileEmission). Everything else will be the same.

Comment: Ok, I get what you're saying. Or can I emit two objects, like `e.onNext("Downloading...", null)`, `e.onNext("Progress 1/4", null)`, and then finally a `e.onNext(null, lfFiles)`? Maybe that would also be ok for me. Like `first parameter = progress` and `second parameter = result`.

Comment: I followed your recommended approach of using a base class and am very satisfied with it. If you extend your answer I'll accept it (also, I'm using only one Observer because one `onNext` is enough, since the differentiation is then made inside the `onNext` of that Observer)

Comment: What do you think about `ofType` operator?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Interesting. As I'm now using `instanceof` in the `onNext` of the Observer, I have no need for it, but if I would use two different Observers, one for each type, that would definitely be my pick. I'm new to Rx, so I'm just discovering; thanks for pointing it out.